# Core OS LDAP Integration

Tags: ldap, openldap, coreos, sssd

I want to integrate coreos with Open LDAP. I don't see documentation in coreos page.

How to install libnss ldap package and proceed?

Any one has the instructions?

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable LDAP, you need to simply configure and start [sssd](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/sssd.html). For more information, read mailing list [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/coreos-user/ldap%7Csort:relevance/coreos-user/e6dXOadWO8s/ScYtmaj2CwAJ).